# C# WPF Serialization XAML with no events

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization

I have dynamically created controls in canvas and when I serialize Canvas events are not serialized.

```
Label label = new Label();
...
label.MouseLeftButtonDown += Control_MouseLeftButtonDown;
label.MouseLeftButtonUp += Control_MouseLeftButtonUp;
label.MouseMove += Control_MouseMove;
label.MouseLeave += Control_MouseLeave;
...

public static string SerializeXAML(UIElement element)
{
    string strXAML = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(element);
    return strXAML;
}

public static UIElement DeserializeXAML(string XAML)
{
    return System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(XAML) as UIElement;
}
```

Serialized strings:

```
<Canvas Background="#FFFFFFFF" Name="DesignCanvas" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Label FontSize="12" Focusable="True" Canvas.Left="363.146190476191" Canvas.Top="179.774339118825" Panel.ZIndex="2">Label</Label></Canvas>
```

I want `<Label ... MouseLeftButtonDown="Control_MouseLeftButtonDown">text</Label>`

it is possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the following MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ms754193(v=vs.90)#Event_Handling_is_Not_Preserved), it is not possible.

> **Event Handling is Not Preserved**
>
> When event handlers that are added through XAML are serialized, they are not preserved. XAML without code-behind (and also without the related x:Code mechanism) has no way of serializing runtime procedural logic. Because serialization is self-contained and limited to the logical tree, there is no facility for storing the event handlers. As a result, event handler attributes, both the attribute itself and the string value that names the handler, are removed from the output XAML.

Comment: i was just about to write the same answer. almost word for word. beat me too it! :)

Comment: Hahaha, jinx no soda for you ;).